# Error al insertar nueva columna con MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un pequeño script en el que quiero insertar una nueva columna a una tabla de la base de datos.

Éste es el contenido del archivo `myscript_ddl.sql`:

```
START TRANSACTION;
ALTER TABLE e1qxp_productos ADD COLUMN `cierre_venta` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL;
COMMIT;
```

Y para ejecutarlo lo hago por línea de comandos de la siguiente forma:

```
mysql -u usuario -pclave nombrebasededatos < myscript_ddl.sql
```

Me lanza el siguiente error y no me deja añadir el campo:

> ERROR 1067 (42000) at line 2: Invalid default value for 'fecha_inicio'

Lo he intentado manualmente desde PhpMyadmin y ocurre exactamente lo mismo, el mismo error. Además hace referencia a `fecha_inicio` que es otra columna de la base de datos que no debería tener nada que ver en la nueva inserción.

¿A qué se debe? ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Edito: Añado la definición de la tabla

```
CREATE TABLE `e1qxp_productos` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `state` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `apellidos` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `nif_cif` char(9) NOT NULL,
  `direccion` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ciudad` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `provincia` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `cp` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `tipo_cliente` enum('persona','empresa') DEFAULT 'persona',
  `tipo_producto` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '-1',
  `fecha_inicio` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `fecha_fin` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `precio` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `marca` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `enviado` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `process` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


-- Indices de la tabla `e1qxp_productos`
--
ALTER TABLE `e1qxp_productos`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

Comment: ¿Podrías decirnos la definición completa de la tabla para poder reproducir tu problema?

Comment: Puedes usar `SHOW CREATE TABLE e1qxp_productos` para obtener la definición exacta.

Comment: Échale un vistazo a esto: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/153237/cannot-alter-mysql-table-stuck-in-a-invalid-default-value-loop?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: ¿Qué versión de MySQL tienes? Imagino que 5.6, ¿me equivoco?

Comment: Tengo la versión 5.7 de MySQL

Comment: Bien, estoy redactando el problema que sufres. Lo dije al revés, la versión 5.6 no se ve afectada por el problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema que sufres es debido a que la fecha [`0000-00-00 00:00:00` es una fecha "virtual"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-types.html) que no provoca error al usarla en un campo de fecha (`TIMESTAMP`, `DATETIME`, `DATE`, etc):

> MySQL permits you to store a “zero” value of `'0000-00-00'` as a “dummy date.” This is in some cases more convenient than using `NULL` values, and uses less data and index space. To disallow `'0000-00-00'`, enable the `NO_ZERO_DATE` SQL mode.

En castellano:

> MySQL permite almacenar una fecha “cero” con valor de `'0000-00-00'` como una “fecha ficticia.” En algunos casos esto es mas conveniente que usar valores `NULL` y usa menos espacio de datos e índice. Para no permitir `'0000-00-00'`, habilite el modo SQL `NO_ZERO_DATE`.

El modo SQL por defecto ha ido variando a lo largo de la versiones:

```
Version  sql_mode
8.0      ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,
         NO_ZERO_DATE, ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,
         NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER, NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
5.7      ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,
         NO_ZERO_DATE, ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,
         NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER, NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
5.6      NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
5.5      (nada)
```

Significa que a partir de la versión 5.7 los modos SQL (`sql_mode`) activan las opciones `NO_ZERO_DATE` y `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` que impiden el uso de fechas "cero" en valores o en la definición de tablas.

## Solución alterando la definición

Todo apunta a que creaste la tabla en una versión anterior de MySQL y tras la actualización estás trabajando con una versión que no te permite modificar la definición sin sustituir ese valor "virtual" de `0000-00-00 00:00:00` por uno real como `NULL`:

```
ALTER TABLE e1qxp_productos
 MODIFY fecha_inicio timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 MODIFY fecha_fin timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

La definición quedaría:

```
CREATE TABLE `e1qxp_productos` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `state` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `apellidos` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `nif_cif` char(9) NOT NULL,
  `direccion` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ciudad` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `provincia` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `cp` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `tipo_cliente` enum('persona','empresa') DEFAULT 'persona',
  `tipo_producto` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '-1',
  `fecha_inicio` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_fin` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `precio` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `marca` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `enviado` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `process` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Puedes probar todo esto en línea en [este enlace](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gp7AMfNra7wbhFoL3w2svA/0).

## Solución alterando el valor de `sql_mode`

Otra opción es modificar de manera permanente el valor de `sql_mode` para que funcione como antes agregando en `my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
sql-mode="ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

O bien de manera temporal:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Comment: Perfecta respuesta!! Muy completa y gran explicación. Lo he entendido a la perfección y he solucionado mi error. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: De nada, me alegra haber sido de ayuda :)

Answer (score 3):

el problema que tienes son los valores que utilizas por defecto para las fechas. En concreto los dos valores que pones a '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

Te recomiendo usar CURRENT_TIMESTAMP como valor por defecto.
También puedes poner la fecha valida mas pequeño posible '1971-01-01 00:00:00', si necesitas ese valor para la lógica de tus algoritmos en otras secciones.

Espero que te sirva la solución.